# Importing different textures in a mesh from blender to Roblox

Tags: texturing

I wan't to make a drawer that has metal handles but wood body and for some reason when I import it as an obj to Roblox studio the handle parts become wood instead of metal which is weird and I can't find the problem please help.[image: The handle bars are suppose to be metal not wood]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Did you UV unwrapped your object?

Comment: what does unwrapping do to it because no I didn't unwrap

Comment: So I guess you have 2 materials in Blender, one for the wood, another one for the handles? Does Roblox accept and understand multiple materials?

Comment: UV unwrap could help you to paint an object with different textures (like wood and metal) and/or Bake your materials into single images that you can export with your 3D object

Comment: Yea Roblox does accept it but I might have done something wrong for it to be like that @moonboots

Comment: How would I do it then because when I unwrap the handles it makes the texture uneven and doesn't look right @Emir

Comment: UV unwrap is not a one click action, there is a process that you need to do in order to get good UVs, it could take from minutes to days of works eve for a simple model. You need to lear about it, start with youtube.